# Where is the second word of power for Kyne's peace?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found the first word during a companion's quest but cant find the others.

Answer (score 9):

The 3 walls with the words to Kyne's Peace are in [Ragnvald](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ragnvald), [Shroud Hearth Barrow](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Shroud_Hearth_Barrow) and [Rannveig's Fast](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rannveig%27s_Fast)

I'm not sure which quest you did, as it may have been a radiance quest, so you'll have to see which on these places you've been to before. I linked entries to the Elder Scrolls Wiki to provide you with more information.

Comment: Kyne's Peace dragon shout, UESP article link: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kyne's_Peace